# SAS 9.2 (64bit) performance on Win 7 (64bit)

Tags: performance, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, sas, 32-bit

I'm looking for documentation/examples/firsthand experience of SAS 64bit performance compared to 32bit in a Windows environment (or any environment if OS has no real impact).

Ideally examples of what kind of performance increases you can expect for various SAS operations when moving from 32bit SAS to 64bit SAS? Specifically, which procs would benefit (proc sort, summary, datastep processing, index building, ) etc if all else stayed the same (ie. no changes to hardware).

Thanks! Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to be changing hardware?

I was running a 64bit machine (not windows 7, though) while running 32bit SAS.  When I upgraded to 64bit SAS I didn't find much, if any, improvement.  Everything was about the same except I could access more memory.

Ultimately, the only real performance difference you could imagine would be ones that were memory intensive.  32bit vs 64bit wont make your processor do any calculations faster.  But if SAS can utilize more memory then, in theory, things would be quicker because it doesn't have to touch the disk as often.